# How to sync Google Calendar and Evolution mail?

Tags: evolution, google-calendar

I am trying to sync Google Calendar with Evolution email client. But I am not able to do so. I tried some of the steps given in web to include Google Calendar and infact I am able to see my entries that I created in Google Calendar

Problem is I cannot save any new appointments entries to Google Calendar through Evolution. Please help me.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Check this on ubuntu wiki: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/GoogleCalendarWithEvolution

This will help you.

Answer (score 2):

With Two-Factor-Authorization (2FA) enabled on your account and/or Google for Business:

1. [Create a new app password for your Google Account](https://myaccount.google.com/u/1/apppasswords)
   *(save this somewhere)*
2. Create a new Calendar in Evolution *(File -> New -> Calendar)*

   URL: `https://www.google.com/calendar/dav/<your email address>/events/`
   User: Your full google account *(user.name@domain.com)*
   Check *"Server handles meeting invitations"*

   Click "OK" and enter your app password, **not** your Google password.

Comment: Thank you Leon. This is also very useful for **Google business accounts**, to allow syncing your work calendar to your smartphone (e.g. with [CardDAV-Sync for Android](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.dmfs.carddav.sync))